# Possible to store value of one select column and use it for the next one?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to store or cache values that are part of one select column and then be used for the next one? For example,

```
select 
       FirstColumn = (complex query returns a value based on ThirdColumn),
       SecondColumn = (uses the same value returned from above + does some additional calculations.)
from SomeTable
```

Is it possible to do something like that so I don't have to write the same complex query twice?

Answer (score 7):

You need `CROSS APPLY` here, it can refer to outer references, no annoying subqueries or CTEs needed:

```sql
select col1, col2
from table1 as outer_table

-- can also have multi-row values
cross apply (values (complex_expression_1) ) as v1 (col1)
cross apply (values (expression_referring_to_col1) ) as v2 (col2)

-- alternate syntax, select without from returns a single row
cross apply (select complex_expression_1 as col1 ) AS v1
cross apply (select expression_referring_to_col1 as col2 ) as v2

-- you can also do anything you like in there, can be one or multiple rows
cross apply (
    select complex_expression_1 as col1 
    from othercomplexjoin as o
    where o.join_column = outer_table.join_column
) AS v1
```

### Some more tricks you can do with `APPLY`:

**1. Top 1 per group of child table:**

A classic solution to the "top 1 per group" is to use `row_number()`. This can often result in huge scans, especially when the number of distinct outer values is small relative to the child table.

```
select
    o.id,
    lastPayment.Date
from order_header as o
join
( select *, row_number() over (partition by order_id order by date desc) as rn
 from payments
) as lastPayment on ...
where lastPayment.rn = 1
```

Instead we can do:

```
select
    o.id,
    lastPayment.Date
from order_header as o
cross apply
( select top (1) *
 from payments as p
 where p.order_id = o.id
 order by date desc
) as lastPayment
```

**Note: `OUTER APPLY` conceptually replaces a left join, i.e. returns nulls instead of no rows.**

---

**2. Unpivoting**

```
select
    o.id,
    customer.*
from order_header as o
cross apply ( values    -- This returns two rows for every order_header
    ( 'DeliveryCustomer', o.deliveryCustomer ),
    ( 'billingCustomer', o.billingCustomer )
) as customer (type, name)
```

---

**3. Exploding out a row a variable number of times:**

Say we want to take an amount, and split it into different rows. If the `amount  <= 50` then one row of `amount`, if `> 50` then two rows, one of 50 and one of the rest:

```
select t.id, v.amount
from table as t
cross apply (
    select case when amount > 50 then 50 else amount end as amount
    union all
    select amount - 50   -- note this row will not appear if amount < 50
    where amount > 50
) v
```

Comment: The `cross apply` is definitely the way to go. However, since OP already has a complex query, why use `values`? Just use a `select` directly.

Comment: I think OP meant "complex calculation" instead of "complex query"

Comment: I mean complex query that performs complex calculations but just returns a single value. How would I directly use the query?

Comment: Have added more possible syntaxes

Answer (score 1):

A sub-query is the simplest form. You can nest sub-queries to any level you like performing calculations along the way:

```
select 
    ComplexValue1 as FirstColumn
    , ComplexValue1 + ComplexValue2 as SecondColumn
from (
  select 
    {complex query returns a value} ComplexValue1
    , {complex query returns a value} ComplexValue2
    , {any other required columns}
  from SomeTable
) X;
```

Note: a CTE is essentially the same thing just *prettier* (maybe).

A lateral join is another option as it allows you to reference columns in the base table and perform calculations on them which are then available for use in the resultset:

```
select
    X.ComplexValue1 as FirstColumn
    , X.ComplexValue1 + ST.ComplexValue2 as SecondColumn
from SomeTable ST
cross apply (select {complex query returns a value referencing ST}) as X (ComplexValue1);
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I always felt (coming from procedural) that lateral made more sense than subquerying for complex expressions. I know some feel different, I guess it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: @Charlieface That depends on what you need it for. My rule is that if you can solve it with a join, then use the join since it is mostly faster. But sometimes a subquery can proof better, depends on what your doing in it

Comment: @GuidoG Obvs yes that is true. I tend to use it for things like: grouped up child tables; top 1 per group; complex calculations on previous tables. Also very useful if you want to double up rows (unpivot), you can even do this conditionally (`union all` with `where` inside the apply) and get different amounts of rows.

Comment: Given the engine has to perform the same operation either way, I would be surprised if there was ever a significant performance difference, although I am sure there is sometimes, but in others I expect identical execution plans. I use both forms, but I think that a well laid out sub-query is more straightforward to follow and understand, especially for a beginner. But as you say its totally a case of personal preference.

Comment: @GuidoG and Dale K. See further edit on my answer

Comment: @Charlieface very clever :) just hope you haven't overloaded the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think in that case, you should use CTE (common table expression). for example

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
 select col1 from table ---- your query 
),
CTE2 as 
(
 select col2 from table --- your query
)
select col1, Col2
from CTE1 join CTE2 on --- do anything you want
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is select the resultset and work from there.

This works by selecting the firstcolumn with all its complex stuff and return it in a resultset called `t`.

```
select t.FirstColumn,
from   ( select FirstColumn --(complex query returns a value based on ThirdColumn)
         from SomeTable
       ) t
```

Then you can very simply select from `t` and it will return `FirstColumn` as if it was a normal simple column, so you can add to it without having to repeat the complex stuff.

```
select t.FirstColumn,
       secondcolum (that uses t.FirstColum as it where a normal field)
from   ( select FirstColumn
         from SomeTable
       ) t
```

An example:

```
select t.FirstColumn,
       (t.FirstColum / 123.0) * 50 as SecondColumn
from   ( select (s.A + s.B) * s.C as FirstColumn
         from   sometable s
       ) t
```

As you can see, I don't need to repeat the calculation for t.Firstcolumn to add stuff to it for my SecondColumn.

Another option is to use `cross apply` (there is an explanation in another answer here so I won't repeat that).
But do test which solution performs best for you, cross apply could have a performance penalty in some cases, and so can my solution. So just test what works best for you.