# How to "duplicate" a row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I begin with SQL Server. I first wrote a query which creates a table. With this table I would like to add some rows.

The code below creates the table.

```
select 
    Element = [Key],
    New = max(case when time_index=1 then value end),
    'Current' = max(case when time_index>=2 then value end)
from
    (select 
         [time_index], B.*
     from   
         (select * 
          from ifrs17.output_bba 
          where id in (602677, 602777)) A
     cross apply 
         (select [Key], Value
          from OpenJson((select A.* FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) 
          where [Key] not in ('time_index')) B
    ) A
group by 
    [Key]
```

The result is here

| Element | New | Current |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 10 | 20 |
| BBB | 15 | 34 |
| CCC | 17 | 22 |

Now, I would like to (for example) duplicate the second row ("BBB") and change the name ("Element") by "DDD".

| Element | New | Current |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 10 | 20 |
| BBB | 15 | 34 |
| CCC | 17 | 22 |
| DDD | 15 | 34 |

Do you have an idea how to proceed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to store value of one select column and use it for the next one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818438/possible-to-store-value-of-one-select-column-and-use-it-for-the-next-one) You will find my answer there useful, see part 3

Comment: If you see the reference I showed you, you will see how to double up as much as you want. Within the `apply`, use whichever combination of `union all` and `where` to get the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if I understand exactly but something like this maybe:

```
with X as 
(
select Element = [Key]
    ,New = max(case when time_index=1 then value end)
    ,'Current' = max(case when time_index>=2 then value end)
From  (
    Select [time_index]
            ,B.*
        From  (select * from ifrs17.output_bba where id in (602677,602777)) A
        Cross Apply (
                    Select [Key]
                        ,Value
                    From OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) ) 
                    Where [Key] not in ('time_index')
                    ) B
    ) A
Group By [Key]
)
select Element, New, [Current] from X 
union all
select 'DDD' as Element, New, [Current] from X where Element = 'BBB'
```

Comment: You can `cross apply` that `union all` and refer to the existing outer query rows, instead of doing another index scan/seek on `X`

Comment: thanks @Charlieface ! it works. What if i would like to add severals rows? for example, duplicate element BBB (as in the example) and duplicate also element CCC ?

Comment: @Charlieface: does cross apply against X not result in two table scans anyway? How do you write that?

Comment: No it doesn't if you use outer references instead of a `from`. I'll give an answer myself Edit: See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Johnny Fitz's answer, you can do this without needing an extra table scan on `X`, by putting the `UNION ALL` inside a `CROSS APPLY` and referenncing the other parts pf the query:

```sql
with X as 
(
select Element = [Key]
    ,New = max(case when time_index=1 then value end)
    ,'Current' = max(case when time_index>=2 then value end)
From  (
    Select [time_index]
            ,B.*
        From  (select * from ifrs17.output_bba where id in (602677,602777)) A
        Cross Apply (
                    Select [Key]
                        ,Value
                    From OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) ) 
                    Where [Key] not in ('time_index')
                    ) B
    ) A
Group By [Key]
)

select
    v.Element,
    X.New,
    X.[Current]
from X 
cross apply (
    select x.Element
    union all
    select 'DDD' as Element
    where X.Element = 'BBB'
) v
```

The `APPLY` conditionally adds an extra row when it encounters `BBB`

Answer (score 0):

In general to duplicate (or multiplicate) rows I use Left JOIN (or INNER JOIN) to VALUES

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable   -- (id,value)
LEFT JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3) )AS t(k)  ON 
--what should be multiplicated and how
(id IN (1,2,3) and k<=2)
or id not in (1,2,3) and k<=3
```

Works with INNER join but then at least 1 row from K has to be joined