# APPLY operator - how does it decide which rows are a match between the two sets?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, apply

When using a JOIN, it is clear exactly what is deciding whether or not the rows will match, e.g. ON a.SomeID1=b.SomeID1. So the only rows returned will be ones where there is a matching 'SomeID1' in the tables referenced by aliases A and B.

My initial thought was that, when using APPLY, a WHERE clause is typically placed within the right-hand query, to provide similar functionality to the ON clause of a JOIN.

However, I see many SQL queries that do not include a WHERE in the right-hand query when using APPLY. So won't this mean that the resulting rows will just be the product of the number of rows from both tables?

**What logic determines which rows will match between the left and right queries when using APPLY?**

I have tried many blog posts, answers on here and even YouTube videos, but none of the explanations have 'clicked' with me.

Comment: Apply "applies" to every row in the data set

Comment: Have you seen this?  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/  Remember that APPLY is an SQL Server extension.  You won't find it in most implementations.

Comment: The key to understanding apply is that its not matching, its applying, it calculating new data based on the existing data which is quite different to joining on separate data.

Comment: In APPLY each row of the left table is CROSS JOINed with the right table that is a function of it. INNER JOIN ON is CROSS JOIN WHERE. CROSS JOIN is INNER JOIN ON TRUE. PS You're just asking for another presentation of APPLY to not understand, without our knowing what you don't understand. Read an authoritative introduction/tutorial/manual & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question where 1st stuck. When you see unexpected examples/results/output, say what you expected instead & why, with justification referencing quoted authoritative documentation. PS Find a textbook. Dozens are online.

Comment: Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: [CROSS JOIN vs INNER JOIN in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

The `apply` operator (in databases that support it) implements a type of `join` called a *lateral join*.

For me, the best way of understanding it starts with a correlated subquery.  For instance:

```
select a.*,
       (select count(*) 
        from b
        where b.a_id = a.a_id
--------------^
       ) as b_count
from a;
```

The subquery is counting the number of matching rows in `b` for each row in `a`.  How does it do this?  The correlation clause is the condition that maps the subquery to the outer query.

`Apply` works the same way:

```
select a.*, b.b_count
from a outer apply
     (select count(*) as b_count
      from b
      where b.a_id = a.a_id
------------^
     ) b;
```

In other words, the *correlation clause* is the answer to your question.

What is the difference between a *lateral join* and a *correlated subquery*?  There are three differences:

- A lateral join can return more than one row.
- A lateral join can return more than one column.
- A lateral join is in the `FROM` clause so the returned columns can be referenced multiple times in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Gordon's excellent answer:

**`APPLY` does not need to be *correlated* (ie that it uses columns from the outer query), the key is that it is *lateral* (it returns a new resultset for *each* row).**

So starting with a base query:

```sql
select c.*
from customer c;
```

**Example Resut:**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Jack |

The idea is to *apply* a new resultset to this. In this case, we only want a single row (a grouped-up count) to apply for each existing row.

Note the `where` correlation, we use an *outer reference*

```sql
select c.*, o.Orders
from customer c
outer apply
     (select count(*) as Orders
      from [order] o
      where o.c_id = c.id
     ) o;
```

| Id | Name | Orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2 |
| 2 | Jack | 0 |

We can, however, return multiple results. In fact, we can return anything we like, and place arbirtrary filters on the result:

```sql
select c.*, t.*
from customer c
outer apply
     (select 'Thing1' thing
     union all
     select 'Thing2'
     where c.Name = 'Jack'
     ) t;
```

| Id | Name | thing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Thing1 |
| 1 | John | Thing2 |
| 2 | Jack | Thing1 |

Note how the row containing `John` got doubled up, based on the filter. Note also that the first half of the `union` has no outer reference.

**See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65818648/14868997) for further `APPLY` tricks.**