# Am I forced to use a CTE or stored procedure instead of a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I want to reduce the size of my code and have a query that **runs as fast as possible**.

I have one CASE expression copy-pasted multiple times within the same SELECT. This is redundant and may run the switch multiple times instead of once, making it slower than it should (Or doesn't it? Does the SQL graph detect the redundant code and reuse results?)

```
-- My view.
SELECT
    /* 20 lines case expression */ + 1 AS a,
    /* 20 lines case expression */ + 2 AS b,
    /* 20 lines case expression */ + 3 AS c,
    /* 20 lines case expression */ + 4 AS d,
FROM some_table
```

To avoid repeating myself I would like to do the following:

```
-- The following code is not valid. It is meant to represent my goal.
SELECT @temp := /* 20 lines case expression */ AS complex
FROM some_table;

SELECT
    @temp + 1 AS a,
    @temp + 2 AS b,
    @temp + 3 AS c,
    @temp + 4 AS d,
FROM some_table
```

But as you may know, user-defined variables are not a thing with views. Also, CTEs are often described as being slow (To which extent and in which situations I do not know).

I would like to use a view alone, is it possible? (speed is more important) If not, then it's fine, I'll just do one of the following.

- Just keep the copy/pasted code
- Use a stored procedure for the case expression (adding to the many procedures cluttering the database)
- Simply using a CTE (because in this case it may be fast?)

Thanks for your help and for sharing your approach to this problem.

UPDATE:

On your demands, here is a more practical example of what I'm dealing with. It's based on legacy code, please do not credit me for it.

```
-- It's a simplified example with small alterations.
SELECT
    -- Nothing special ...
    [col_x] AS X,
    [col_y] AS Y,
    [col_z] AS Z,
    -- Then there is this column...
    CASE
        WHEN
            [col_a] + ' ' +
            CASE
                WHEN [col_b] = 'some_code' THEN 'something'
                ELSE 'something_else'
            END + ' ' +
            CASE
                WHEN [col_c] IN ('a', 'b', 'c') THEN 'something'
                ELSE 'something_else'
            END = 'First thing to compare with'
        THEN [return_First],
        WHEN
            [col_a] + ' ' +
            CASE
                WHEN [col_b] = 'some_code' THEN 'something'
                ELSE 'something_else'
            END + ' ' +
            CASE
                WHEN [col_c] IN ('a', 'b', 'c') THEN 'something'
                ELSE 'something_else'
            END = 'Second thing to compare with'
        THEN [return_Second],
        WHEN
            [col_a] + ' ' +
            CASE
                WHEN [col_b] = 'some_code' THEN 'something'
                ELSE 'something_else'
            END + ' ' +
            CASE
                WHEN [col_c] IN ('a', 'b', 'c') THEN 'something'
                ELSE 'something_else'
            END = 'Second thing to compare with'
        THEN [return_Third]
    END AS [Monster Case Expression That Makes Me Cry]
FROM some_table
```

Comment: Going to dump the same comment that I put in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66706367/2029983) before you immediately deleted it: *"
A `VIEW` can't have variables. If you don't want to repeat a specific expression then define it in a CTE or `VALUES` construct."*

Comment: Also, the comment in your code says *"20 lines switch case-statement"*; T-SQL doesn't support `Switch`/`Case` statements.

Comment: @Larnu This question is for Microsoft sql-server. I run Switch Cases on it just fine. ;)

Comment: No, you don't. Again, T-SQL does **not** support `Switch` statements. Never has done.

Comment: @Larnu I am not using T-SQL. I am on Microsoft sql-server. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. And I am working in a very very old database with many statements following this pattern (just in case there is a misunderstanding) CASE SWITCH ... = ... THEN 'return_this' ELSE 'return_that' END

Comment: SQL Server uses T-SQL, Florian... T-SQL (Transact-SQL) is the specific dialect that Microsoft SQL Server and SyBase uses. The only `CASE` that T-SQL supports is a [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) **expression** and there is no `SWITCH` expression in T-sQL.

Comment: I suspect you are *not* really using SQL Server. Without the actual code, it is impossible to identify the RDBMS. The fact you have `SELECT @temp :=` also indicates it is not T-SQL.#

Comment: *"I am not mad! I am healthy and alive! "* That is a `CASE` **expression** Florian, not a `Case`/`Switch` statement. I can repeat this till I go blue, as it's true (at the time of writing): **T-SQL does not support `Case`/`Switch` statements.**

Comment: Understood. I will modify my question. CASE expression instead of CASE-Statement. Makes sense. Thanks for correcting it.

Comment: Either way, like I mentioend at the start, I would still use a CTE or `VALUES` table construct. Without actual meaningful code, this is difficult to demonstrate. I suggest, perhaps, looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-specifying-multiple-values-as-a-derived-table-in-a-from-clause) and then ask if you don't understand; with your attempts or description of what you don't understand.

Comment: Just create your query like `select ... from (select ..) x` - you can evaluate your complex epressions in inner query and use its results in outer one.

Comment: Please show your actual code, `CROSS APPLY(VALUES` should do the trick. And CTEs are not slow, or any slower than a view, it just depends how you use them

Comment: @Larnu Sorry for the confusion! Now, my worry is that a CTE would be very slow compared to a view. While I will make one and test it right now, I need to know if the CTEs reputation to be slow is due to poor use by new developers or due to some kind of processes not being adapted for CTEs. btw +2 ups for your patience. Thanks! ;)

Comment: @Charlieface Ok! I'll complete my working example.

Comment: "CTEs are known to be extremely slow.". Only in the same way that queries are slow, stored procedures are slow, views are slow, etc. They are not, in and off themselves a "do things dumb now" switch. Rather than presuming slowness, use one and *measure* performance, and if it's adequate, use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to put the expression in an `APPLY`, which means you can re-use it anywhere in the query:

```sql
SELECT
    v1.Temp + 1 AS a,
    v1.Temp + 2 AS b,
    v1.Temp + 3 AS c,
    v1.Temp + 4 AS d,
FROM some_table
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CASE WHEN /* 20 lines case expression */
    END
) ) AS v1(Temp)
```

Comment: Couldn't agree more. DRY your code with cross apply ftw.

Comment: I hereby promise that I will be learning the ins and outs of the APPLY expression.  It just cut in half the processing time of my query from 12s to 5s (to verify)

Comment: And it cut the size of my query by about 50% too.

Comment: @FlorianFasmeyer See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65818648/14868997

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as:

```
SELECT 
    CaseColumn + 1 AS a,
    CaseColumn + 2 AS b,
    CaseColumn + 3 AS c,
    CaseColumn + 4 AS d
FROM (
    SELECT
        /* 20 lines case expression */ AS CaseColumn
    FROM some_table
)
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, so I gave you +1. But Charlieface's answer is even more useful to me. Thanks and thanks again! You're awesome! :)