# Double substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

in my table, I have a column that contains two IDs:

example:

| Comment |
| --- |
| Internal message ID: 7878 External message ID: 788CBNCGD9_3_5_87BFHJD |
| Internal message ID: 90278 External message ID: 788H2692029_3_5_8890ZG |

I want to get two columns: Internal Id and External ID

| Internal ID | External ID |
| --- | --- |
| 7878 | 788CBNCGD9_3_5_87BFHJD |
| 90278 | 788H2692029_3_5_8890ZG |

I’ve been thinking about using the substring but I don’t know how.

Can someone help me?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, I would suggest fixing your design at source, and not inserting what is essentially delimited data into your database that you then want to consume.

Saying that, however, on the sample data we have you can achieve this with SQL Server's rudimentary string manipulation:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(V.Comment,CI1.I,CI2.I-CI1.I),
       SUBSTRING(V.Comment,CI3.I, ISNULL(NULLIF(CI4.I,0),LEN(V.Comment)+1)  - CI3.I)
FROM (VALUES('Internal message ID: 7878 External message ID: 788CBNCGD9_3_5_87BFHJD'),
            ('Internal message ID: 90278 External message ID: 788H2692029_3_5_8890ZG'))V(Comment)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(':',V.Comment)+2))CI1(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',V.Comment,CI1.I)))CI2(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(':',V.Comment,CI2.I)+2))CI3(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',V.Comment,CI3.I)))CI4(I);
```

Comment: `NULLIF(..., 0)` on every `CHARINDEX` would be a good idea, just in case it can't find it

Comment: @Charlieface I did consider it, but with 2 examples, I felt I lacked information to suggest that the data didn't meet the data *could* follow a different format.

Comment: IMO it's wise to *always* do so, because if there are any at all in the base table, even if they are filtered with a `WHERE` or a join, often the function calculation is pushed through to before predicate filtering, and can therefore cause an error. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/67259538/14868997

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still of mind of that the *if* that is a scenario, @Charlieface, then additional examples were needed.