# How do I update column in SQL by removing preceding characters in column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help in updating records in my table `[Fruit]`. Currently, I have number - name (ie `1234 - Apple`) value which I would like to replace with `Apple` from all the records (the number preceding is not the same).

```
Date       ItemNo    Fruit   
---------------------------------
01/10/10   1234      1234 - Apple
01/12/10   5546      5546 - Banana
```

I want to only remove the preceding `number -`  from the column **Fruit**.

```
Date       ItemNo    Fruit   
---------------------------------
01/10/10   1234      Apple
01/12/10   5546      Banana
```

How do I do this for all rows in my table?

Comment: Use `replace`; if your data was properly normalised with columns storing atomic values you wouldn't have a problem!

Comment: `STUFF`, with `CHARINDEX` would also be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following:

```
update t set fruit=Replace(fruit, Concat(itemno, ' - '),'')
```

Comment: `WHERE fruit LIKE CONCAT(itemno, ' - %')`?

Answer (score 2):

If the Fruit field will always have a dash '-' and it will always have a space between the dash and the text to the right of it then you can use `substring` with `charindex` to extract the string on the right of the dash like so:

```
update F 
set F.Fruit = substring(F.Fruit, charindex('-', F.Fruit) + 2, len(F.Fruit))
from Fruit as F
```

`charindex` gets the location of the dash, then returns the location 2 to the right of that, which will be the start of your string.

Comment: REALLY needs a `WHERE` clause, ***just in case*** the assertion that `the Fruit field will always have a dash '-' and it will always have a space between the dash and the text to the right of it` fails for some rows.

Comment: @MatBailie I'm afraid even a `WHERE` is not good enough, it also needs `NULLIF` or `CASE` on the `CHARINDEX`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67259538/14868997