# Sql sort script based on one column that has odd or even value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-scripts

I need help devising a sql script that will sort a bay item, based on the column value. If the level column value is even, then the bay ascends, but if the level column is odd, then bay descends. I have 12 levels, and 54 bays per level. So, shortened example (disregard dots after level number)

```
Level  Bay
    1    5
    1    4
    1   54
    1   13
    2    8
    2    3
    2    4
```

Result

```
Level  Bay
    1    4
    1    5
    1   13
    1   54
    2    8
    2    4
    2    3
```

Here is the script as it gives a conversion failed error when converting the varchar level to an int.

```
SELECT cast (SUBSTRING(cm.description, CHARINDEX('Bay:', cm.description) + 4, CHARINDEX(' ', cm.description, CHARINDEX('Bay:', cm.description)) - CHARINDEX('Bay:', cm.description) - 4) AS INT)      AS Bay,
       cast (SUBSTRING(cm.description, CHARINDEX('Level:', cm.description) + 6, CHARINDEX(' ', cm.description, CHARINDEX('Level:', cm.description)) - CHARINDEX('Level:', cm.description) - 6)AS INT) AS level
FROM   [Test].[Test].[Stations] AS cm
WHERE  ( cm.StationTypeId = '1' )
ORDER  BY CASE 'level' % 2
            WHEN 0 THEN 'bay'
            WHEN 1 THEN '-bay'
          END;
```

Here is what the description column looks like for each level:

```
Aisle:1 Bay:1 Level:1 Side:E
```

Comment: Column references should not be in single quotes. Also you can't use column aliases defined at the same level in expressions in `ORDER BY` (if you use them they must be on their own). So probably you need something like https://dbfiddle.uk/HlCA-J0x

Comment: Martin this does work; however, if I wanted to use left or full outer join, is that possible? The reason I ask is that this task is a subset of code from my entire sql script. Could you provide a version of this using a join statement?

Comment: I'm sure its possible but you should edit your question demonstrating what you actually need. I'm not going to guess it and just invent and solve a fictitious requirement

Comment: Hello, I tried to post the entire script but it's not allowing it.

Comment: Martin I've placed a screenshot of the entire code is why I asked.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/4V-PWxMR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `bay` is actually a string, you can't use the other answer's trick of negating it.

Instead, use separate clauses.

you also cannot sort by a calcualtion on a field created in the `SELECT`. Instead put it into an `APPLY` subquery.

```
SELECT
  v.bay,
  v.level
FROM Test.Stations AS cm
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      cast (SUBSTRING(cm.description, CHARINDEX('Bay:', cm.description) + 4, CHARINDEX(' ', cm.description, CHARINDEX('Bay:', cm.description)) - CHARINDEX('Bay:', cm.description) - 4) AS INT)      AS Bay,
      cast (SUBSTRING(cm.description, CHARINDEX('Level:', cm.description) + 6, CHARINDEX(' ', cm.description, CHARINDEX('Level:', cm.description)) - CHARINDEX('Level:', cm.description) - 6)AS INT) AS level
) AS v
WHERE  cm.StationTypeId = '1'
order by
    v.level,
    case when v.level % 2 = 1 then bay end asc,
    case when v.level % 2 = 0 then bay end desc;
```

Comment: It's shows invalid columns when using this. Is there something additional I should add to get it to recognize bay and level are columns?

Comment: @ShurondaHawkins Fixed now, see edit

Comment: @MartinSmith good point didn't read the question properly.

Comment: Charlie there is more to the script in which I have about 5 join statements. Is there any way to devise the script so that it doesn't use cross apply?

Comment: Why can't you use `CROSS APPLY` in such a script? It's pretty simple to use. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65818648/14868997

Comment: I placed a screenshot of the entire code set.

Comment: Screenshots are useless, but yeah you can just place the `CROSS APPLY` at the end just before `ORDER BY`

Comment: @MartinSmith adding it to the bottom of the screenshotted script causes it to produce two separate tables. I attempted to add level and bay in the main select, but it doesn't recognize them as columns or values.

Comment: Like I keep saying, you need to add the `CROSS APPLY` to your existing script then it will recognize them. The screenshot is useless, I cannot copy/paste it as text. Please paste it in as text instead.

Comment: Thanks so much. I got it incorporated into my existing script. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
order by
    level,
    case level % 2
        when 0 then -bay
        when 1 then  bay
    end
```

Comment: Is the -level a typo?

Comment: No, it's a negative number. That's how you get it to reverse on odd vs even.

Comment: I'll have to see what else may be wrong. It is giving an invalid column name when I add the negative.

Comment: I had added in a comma between the two sort levels in case you did a copy and paste. No sure what error you'd see without it though.

Comment: Shuronda, I may have had your sort orders reversed. Obviously the fundamentals of the answer are the same regardless.

Comment: If it is giving an invalid column name when adding the negative it is probably a column alias for an expression in the SELECT

Comment: Yes Martin, I had to use substring to pull the column and bay out of the string. Is there a way around it?

Comment: I've added more details to the explanation.