# Are calculations to a field available within the same SQL UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 13.

Here is an example:

```
UPDATE table
SET
  sum_col = col_1 + col_2,
  another_sum_col = sum_col + col_3;
```

Should the calculations in `sum_col` be available for the next field's calculation (`another_sum_col`)?

What I'm working on is more complex than that and I'm encountering discrepancies that might be explained if the calculations aren't available within the same `UPDATE`. In other words, I'd need to run a second `UPDATE`.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this one, but my assumption is that: No, the value of `sum_col` used in the `another_sum_col` calculation would be the original value in that row, not the newly assigned value in the SET clause. Edit: [This dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/B_z4SvCE) shows that assumption to be true.

Comment: No per [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html): *expression
An expression to assign to the column. The expression can use the old values of this and other columns in the table.*.

Comment: Should have added this could be accomplished with a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger on the table.

Comment: @JNevill It's part of the SQL specification that that is always the case. See also [How database engine of SQL swap two columns values?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/317528/220697)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No it's not available.** The SQL Standard is clear on this: right-side of the `SET` part of an `UPDATE` [only takes the "before" values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/317528/220697), not the "after" values. MySQL and MariaDB do not follow this, but they do not follow the spec.

But you don't need a second `UPDATE`, you can use a correlated (lateral) calculation. This is [a generalized technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818438/possible-to-store-value-of-one-select-column-and-use-it-for-the-next-one?r=Saves_AllUserSaves) for making available intermediate calculations without using a new level of derived table or view.

Annoyingly, in Postgres you cannot use columns from the table to be updated in a lateral join. The only way I can see is to self-join the table. (SQL Server however allows you to use the table being updated directly.)

```sql
UPDATE yourtable
SET
  sum_col = v.newSumCol,
  another_sum_col = v.NewSumCol + yourtable.col_3
FROM yourtable t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT t.col_1 + t.col_2 AS newSumCol
  ) v
WHERE t.yourPK = yourtable.yourPK;
```

You can also do this in a `SELECT` as mentioned

```sql
SELECT
  v.newSumCol
  v.NewSumCol + yourtable.col_3 AS another_sum_col
FROM yourtable t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT col_1 + col_2 AS newSumCol
  ) v;
```